# XSLT transformation of SOAP response

Tags: .net, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I am trying to download and transform soap response from Magyar Nemzeti Bank. I managed to get the downloading part right, now I am having a problem with xslt transformation. I want to transform the message to xml so I can deserialize it.

The SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
   <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
     <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>
       <MNBCurrentExchangeRates>
         <Day date="2013-12-03">
           <Rate curr="AUD" unit="1">203,5</Rate>
           <Rate curr="BGN" unit="1">154,82</Rate>
           <Rate curr="BRL" unit="1">94,69</Rate>
           <Rate curr="CAD" unit="1">209,79</Rate>
           <Rate curr="CHF" unit="1">246,21</Rate>
           <Rate curr="CNY" unit="1">36,62</Rate>
           <Rate curr="CZK" unit="1">11,02</Rate>
           <Rate curr="DKK" unit="1">40,59</Rate>
           <Rate curr="EUR" unit="1">302,8</Rate>
           <Rate curr="GBP" unit="1">366,05</Rate>
           <Rate curr="HKD" unit="1">28,78</Rate>
           <Rate curr="HRK" unit="1">39,67</Rate>
           <Rate curr="IDR" unit="100">1,88</Rate>
           <Rate curr="ILS" unit="1">63,32</Rate>
           <Rate curr="INR" unit="1">3,58</Rate>
           <Rate curr="ISK" unit="1">1,87</Rate>
           <Rate curr="JPY" unit="100">217,08</Rate>
           <Rate curr="KRW" unit="100">21,04</Rate>
           <Rate curr="LTL" unit="1">87,71</Rate>
           <Rate curr="LVL" unit="1">430,68</Rate>
           <Rate curr="MXN" unit="1">16,89</Rate>
           <Rate curr="MYR" unit="1">69,33</Rate>
           <Rate curr="NOK" unit="1">36,46</Rate>
           <Rate curr="NZD" unit="1">183,65</Rate>
           <Rate curr="PHP" unit="1">5,1</Rate>
           <Rate curr="PLN" unit="1">72,03</Rate>
           <Rate curr="RON" unit="1">67,89</Rate>
           <Rate curr="RSD" unit="1">2,65</Rate>
           <Rate curr="RUB" unit="1">6,71</Rate>
           <Rate curr="SEK" unit="1">34,08</Rate>
           <Rate curr="SGD" unit="1">177,85</Rate>
           <Rate curr="THB" unit="1">6,93</Rate>
           <Rate curr="TRY" unit="1">109,6</Rate>
           <Rate curr="UAH" unit="1">27,14</Rate>
           <Rate curr="USD" unit="1">223,09</Rate>
           <Rate curr="ZAR" unit="1">21,59</Rate>
         </Day>
       </MNBCurrentExchangeRates>
     </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult> 
   </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="list">           
            <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult" /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT works as excpected, but I can´t get any deeper than that. Every time I am trying to get to the MNBCurrentExchangeRates element, select result is empty. (I tryied ws:MNBCurrentExchangeRates, *[local-name()='MNBCurrentExchangeRates'] and many other less realistic options)

If it helps, spec for this soap request states that content of GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult element is string:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
      <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>string</GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>
    </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to get Day and Rate elements and select them?

Thanks,
kwitee

EDIT: 
I tried both user3016153's and Mathias Müller's answers and none of them worked for me so let me change the question:

Why this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="list">           
            <xsl:value-of select="//ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult" /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is working and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="list">           
            <xsl:value-of select="//ws:MNBCurrentExchangeRates" /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is not?

Mathias Müller's answer created this result (xml encoding is somehow broken and date acces doesn't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>&lt;MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;&lt;Day date="2013-12-03"&gt;&lt;Rate curr="AUD" unit="1"&gt;203,5&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="BGN" unit="1"&gt;154,82&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="BRL" unit="1"&gt;94,69&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CAD" unit="1"&gt;209,79&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CHF" unit="1"&gt;246,21&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CNY" unit="1"&gt;36,62&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CZK" unit="1"&gt;11,02&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="DKK" unit="1"&gt;40,59&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="EUR" unit="1"&gt;302,8&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="GBP" unit="1"&gt;366,05&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="HKD" unit="1"&gt;28,78&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="HRK" unit="1"&gt;39,67&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="IDR" unit="100"&gt;1,88&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ILS" unit="1"&gt;63,32&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="INR" unit="1"&gt;3,58&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ISK" unit="1"&gt;1,87&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="JPY" unit="100"&gt;217,08&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="KRW" unit="100"&gt;21,04&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="LTL" unit="1"&gt;87,71&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="LVL" unit="1"&gt;430,68&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="MXN" unit="1"&gt;16,89&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="MYR" unit="1"&gt;69,33&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="NOK" unit="1"&gt;36,46&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="NZD" unit="1"&gt;183,65&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="PHP" unit="1"&gt;5,1&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="PLN" unit="1"&gt;72,03&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RON" unit="1"&gt;67,89&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RSD" unit="1"&gt;2,65&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RUB" unit="1"&gt;6,71&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="SEK" unit="1"&gt;34,08&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="SGD" unit="1"&gt;177,85&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="THB" unit="1"&gt;6,93&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="TRY" unit="1"&gt;109,6&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="UAH" unit="1"&gt;27,14&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="USD" unit="1"&gt;223,09&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ZAR" unit="1"&gt;21,59&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;/Day&gt;&lt;/MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;
```

I am pasting .NET code to complete the question:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    xslt.Load(xsltPath);
    xslt.Transform(xmlDoc.CreateNavigator(), null, writer);
    string xml = writer.ToString();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        return (List)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me you are somehow reading the XML as text, instead of parsing it as XML. Can you explain what is your final intended result? Perhaps it can all be accomplished in XSLT.

Comment: I want to process 5 different XML into the same template, deserialize it into .NET objects and then save it to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I misled you. The thing is that the SOAP response is partially escaped:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
            <GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>&lt;MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;&lt;Day date="2013-12-04"&gt;&lt;Rate curr="AUD" unit="1"&gt;200,46&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="BGN" unit="1"&gt;154,44&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="BRL" unit="1"&gt;93,56&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CAD" unit="1"&gt;208,25&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CHF" unit="1"&gt;245,79&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CNY" unit="1"&gt;36,49&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="CZK" unit="1"&gt;11,02&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="DKK" unit="1"&gt;40,49&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="EUR" unit="1"&gt;302,05&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="GBP" unit="1"&gt;363,71&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="HKD" unit="1"&gt;28,67&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="HRK" unit="1"&gt;39,53&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="IDR" unit="100"&gt;1,85&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ILS" unit="1"&gt;63,13&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="INR" unit="1"&gt;3,57&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ISK" unit="1"&gt;1,86&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="JPY" unit="100"&gt;216,66&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="KRW" unit="100"&gt;20,94&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="LTL" unit="1"&gt;87,5&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="LVL" unit="1"&gt;429,71&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="MXN" unit="1"&gt;16,89&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="MYR" unit="1"&gt;68,9&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="NOK" unit="1"&gt;36,35&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="NZD" unit="1"&gt;181,92&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="PHP" unit="1"&gt;5,07&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="PLN" unit="1"&gt;71,9&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RON" unit="1"&gt;67,62&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RSD" unit="1"&gt;2,63&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="RUB" unit="1"&gt;6,68&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="SEK" unit="1"&gt;34,08&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="SGD" unit="1"&gt;177,05&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="THB" unit="1"&gt;6,89&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="TRY" unit="1"&gt;108,51&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="UAH" unit="1"&gt;26,96&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="USD" unit="1"&gt;222,29&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Rate curr="ZAR" unit="1"&gt;21,4&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;/Day&gt;&lt;/MNBCurrentExchangeRates&gt;</GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult>
        </GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I exported the XML from Visual Studio and it automaticaly replaced < and >. But the web service is really treating contents of GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult as string.

I spend almost whole day doing this.

**Thanks everyone who helped me solve this problem.**

Final XSLT that worked for me - require exsl:node-set function (in case someone would need it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult">
        <xsl:element name="kurzovni_listek">
            <xsl:variable name="details" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="parsedXml_">
                <xsl:call-template name="parseXml">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$details"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="parsedXml" select="exsl:node-set($parsedXml_)"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="banka"><xsl:text>MNB</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="datum">
                <xsl:value-of select="$parsedXml/MNBCurrentExchangeRates/Day/@date"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="$parsedXml/MNBCurrentExchangeRates/Day/Rate">
                <xsl:element name="kurz">
                    <xsl:attribute name="mena">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@curr"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="nasobek">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@unit"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="hodnota">
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ',', '.')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="parseXml">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&gt;')">
                <xsl:variable name="topLevelTag">
                    <xsl:call-template name="getTopLevelTag">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="openingTag">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$topLevelTag"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="tagName">
                    <xsl:call-template name="getTopLevelTagName">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="closingTag">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',$tagName,'&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="firstNode">
                    <xsl:if test="not(contains($topLevelTag,'/&gt;'))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text,$openingTag),$closingTag)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="afterFirstNode">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains($topLevelTag,'/&gt;'))">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,concat($firstNode,$closingTag))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,$topLevelTag)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
                    <xsl:call-template name="createAttributes">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$topLevelTag"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="parseXml">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$firstNode"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:call-template name="parseXml">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$afterFirstNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="getTopLevelTagName">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&gt;')">
                <xsl:variable name="tagWithAttributesWithoutEnd">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="tagWithAttributesWithoutBegining">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($tagWithAttributesWithoutEnd, '&lt;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="tagName">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($tagWithAttributesWithoutBegining,' ')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($tagWithAttributesWithoutBegining, ' ')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$tagWithAttributesWithoutBegining"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$tagName"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="getTopLevelTag">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&gt;')">
                <xsl:variable name="tagWithAttributesWithoutEnd">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($tagWithAttributesWithoutEnd,'&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="createAttributes">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, '=&quot;')">
                <xsl:variable name="attributeName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text,' '),'=&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="attributeValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text,concat($attributeName,'=&quot;')),'&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$attributeName}"><xsl:value-of select="$attributeValue"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:call-template name="createAttributes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,concat($attributeName,'=&quot;',$attributeValue,'&quot;'))"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I mean, have you checked this at the source?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it in .NET as a string and this result came up. After all, web service spec was telling me this all along.

Comment: Well, I suppose you can still parse the string *as text*, with a lot of unnecessary work. Even so, it makes mo sense for them to provide it this way (and call it a "service").

Comment: I managed to translate it with the help of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592627/xslt-how-to-transform-partially-escaped-xml).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to access the `Day` and `Rate` elements. It processes all `Day` elements in an `xsl:for-each` expression and matches `Rate` elements in a separate template.

Also note that this line:

```
<xsl:template match="//ws:MNBCurrentExchangeRates">
```

selects `MNBCurrentExchangeRates` elements no matter where they are in the document. That way, you are spared the exercise of navigating this lengthy tree. (If your goal is indeed to get at the Day and Rate elements).

The **stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ws">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ws:MNBCurrentExchangeRates">
  <xsl:element name="list">
     <xsl:for-each select="ws:Day">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:attribute name="date">
              <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ws:Rate">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*|text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This yields the following **output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
 <Day xmlns="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    date="2013-12-03">
  <Rate curr="AUD" unit="1">203,5</Rate>
  <Rate curr="BGN" unit="1">154,82</Rate>
  <Rate curr="BRL" unit="1">94,69</Rate>
  <Rate curr="CAD" unit="1">209,79</Rate>
  <Rate curr="CHF" unit="1">246,21</Rate>
  <Rate curr="CNY" unit="1">36,62</Rate>
  <Rate curr="CZK" unit="1">11,02</Rate>
  <Rate curr="DKK" unit="1">40,59</Rate>
  <Rate curr="EUR" unit="1">302,8</Rate>
  <Rate curr="GBP" unit="1">366,05</Rate>
  <Rate curr="HKD" unit="1">28,78</Rate>
  <Rate curr="HRK" unit="1">39,67</Rate>
  <Rate curr="IDR" unit="100">1,88</Rate> 
  <!--And so on...-->   
 </Day>
</list>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the output over the input?

Comment: This is not what the OP asks. I have merely answered the question: "Is there a way to get Day and Rate elements and select them?". So, I agree, there's no advantage over the input structure. Rather, I have tried to show how to access the said nodes. (n.b. even if you enrich the output in a way, see your solution, how do you know it is advantageous or not without knowing the OP's intent?).

Comment: "This is not what the OP asks." No, of course not - that was what ***I*** asked. Because if the OP has difficulty consuming the input, they will have the same difficulty with the output, I think. And you are correct, I am only guessing the OP's intent. This guess is based upon what the data should look like if entered into a database.

Comment: No need for hostility between the two of us - I acknowledge your remark. +1 for your solution that also intelligently guesses the OP's intent.

Comment: Absolutely, no hostility intended. It was a honest question, I am sorry if you took it on the defensive. Let the OP clarify what they need.

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work for me. I edited the question and I hope the problem is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a for-each statement. Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap ws">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResponse/ws:GetCurrentExchangeRatesResult/ws:MNBCurrentExchangeRates/ws:Day/ws:Rate">
            <rate>
                <date><xsl:value-of select="../@date"/></date>
                <curr><xsl:value-of select="@curr"/></curr>
                <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
            </rate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>       
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will produce a result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <rate>
    <date>2013-12-03</date>
    <curr>AUD</curr>
    <value>203,5</value>
  </rate>
  <rate>
    <date>2013-12-03</date>
    <curr>BGN</curr>
    <value>154,82</value>
  </rate>
  <rate>
    <date>2013-12-03</date>
    <curr>BRL</curr>
    <value>94,69</value>
  </rate>
  ...
  <rate>
    <date>2013-12-03</date>
    <curr>USD</curr>
    <value>223,09</value>
  </rate>
  <rate>
    <date>2013-12-03</date>
    <curr>ZAR</curr>
    <value>21,59</value>
  </rate>
</list>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work for me. I edited the question and I hope the problem is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your new question: both stylesheets work in the same way and produce a result in the form of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list xmlns:ws="http://www.mnb.hu/webservices/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

203,5
154,82
94,69
209,79
...
223,09
21,59

</list>
```

The **only** difference between them is the number of blank lines surrounding the values (either one or two). I am not sure how this helps. I am not a .NET programmer, so I am afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: You're right. I tried this in Altova XMLSpy and it worked. I think the problem is on .NET side.